# Getting an error when trying to set up Turso database

Tags: sqlite, backend, bun, drizzle

I follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/ethanniser/the-beth-stack) to set up a web app using Bun, Htmx, Turso and Elysium. The problem is trying to set up the database. I created my account and put the database URL and auth token in .env file, but I couldn't get it to work, even with the original GitHub project. The error:

```
\[0.04ms\] ".env"
No config path provided, using default 'drizzle.config.ts'
Reading config file '/home/mozart/the-beth-stack/drizzle.config.ts'
drizzle-kit: v0.19.6
drizzle-orm: v0.27.2

37869 |       code;
37870 |       constructor(message, code, cause) {
37871 |         if (code !== void 0) {
37872 |           message = `${code}: ${message}`;
37873 |         }
37874 |         super(message, { cause });
^
LibsqlError: HRANA_WEBSOCKET_ERROR: Unexpected server response: 401
code: "HRANA_WEBSOCKET_ERROR"

      at new LibsqlError (/home/mozart/the-beth-stack/node_modules/drizzle-kit/index.cjs:37874:8)
      at mapHranaError (/home/mozart/the-beth-stack/node_modules/drizzle-kit/index.cjs:42986:11)
      at /home/mozart/the-beth-stack/node_modules/drizzle-kit/index.cjs:43120:16
```

I am using WSL2 with Ubuntu 22.04. I managed to run the Drizzle Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You need an Intel pc with the latest WSL. I was struggling for days on my AMD desktop. If you run bun dev. It will fail but if you read the message after pressing ctrl+c you will see a missing kernel function. The truth is bun utilizing a CPU instruction that wasn't in my AMD pc.
The latest WSL can be grabbed with "wsl.exe --update".

So yeah just switch to Intel.

Comment: Im using an Intel Core I5 11th Gen. But I agree with you that my problem is related to using WSL. After looking some people talking how Bun isnt really made to run in Windows, even WSL.